# How to improve ray parallelization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, ray

I am new to ray and am trying to parallelize some big data computations.

I have a large array (8 x 768937392), referred to X_np in my code below, on which I need to perform computations on - these computations are not expensive (hence I tried splitting the large task also into tiny tasks), but due to the large array I am running into problems. From what I understand, ideally I would only send this array to the object store once, using ray.put(X_np), put I am struggling to then obtain the values again (ray.get(...)), without it becoming much slower. The below code works on a test dataset, but is not efficient enough to run on the entire dataset.

Any help on this/suggestions on improvement would be very much appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
import ray
import psutil

def tiny_work(X_np):
    output = sum(X_np[2:])  # dummy function
    return (output,X_np[0],X_np[1])  # X_np[0] and X_np[1] are i,j locations in 2d array

@ray.remote
def mega_work(result,X_np,start, end):
    return [tiny_work(X_np[:,x]) for x in range(0, end-start)]

num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
start = time.time()
ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus)
n_test=499  # arbitrary split, which improved speed for test dateset the most
result_ids = []
[result_ids.append(mega_work.remote(X_np[:,x * n_test:(x + 1) * n_test],x * n_test, (x + 1) * n_test)) for x in range(int(X_np.shape[1]/n_test)-1)]
results = ray.get(result_ids)
ray.shutdown()
print("duration =", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: What ray tracing module are you using?  You're talking about moving 50GB of data here; it's never going to speedy.  Your line `[result_ids.append(...) for x in range()]` is not the right way to do that.  Just do `result_ids = [mega_work.remove(...) for x in range()]`.  That builds a single list instead of making a bunch of `append` calls.

Comment: What is X_np/how are you loading it? You mention the computation is not expensive, so it's possible that you're IO bound, not compute bound, in which case you may want to parallelize the loading of X_np itself.